# XML-RPC PHP only sends empty array

Tags: php, joomla, xml-rpc, joomla2.5

I'm running this on a server, using Joomla's implementation of XMLRPC for PHP.  Whatever xmlrpcval I try to send (including `null`) is not sent.  Instead, an empty array is sent.

Relevant Master code.  I've tried different varieties of xmlrpcmsg sent (from a complicated array to a simple string):

```
$articleData = new xmlrpcmsg("insertContent", array(new xmlrpcval($articleArray, "struct")));
$client = new xmlrpc_client("/administrator/components/com_quickagencyslave/remote/easyblog.php", $clientArray["url"]);
$response = $client->send($articleData);
```

Slave code (not actual functionality, just trying to get it to work:

```
function insertContent($params){        
    $data = $params->getParam(0);
    $result = gettype($data);

    return new xmlrpcresp(new xmlrpcval($result));
}
```

Return codes show that `$data` is of type `NULL`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out XMLRPC is very strict about what data it will accept (something that isn't entirely reflected in the [docs](http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/doc-2/)).  An array can't contain plain objects, even if that array has been converted into an XMLRPC object.  The code below wraps an array and everything in it into an XMLRPC struct:

```
//Takes an array containing strings, returns an xmlrpc array of xmlrpcvals
function xmlrpcpack($input){
    if(is_array($input)){
        $return = array();
        foreach($input as $item){
            if(gettype($item) === "array")
                $return[] = xmlrpcpack($item);
            else
                $return[] = new xmlrpcval($item);
        }
        return new xmlrpcval($return, "array");
    }else{
        debug_print_backtrace();
    }
}
```